# How to format string containing date like "Mon Oct 17 00:00:00 UTC-0300 2016" to dd/MM/yyyy

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, telerik-mvc

I'm using a hierarchical telerik mvc grid, and I need to pass fields from the parent grid to controller action as parameters so I can use them to excecute a stored procedure, which will show its results in the child grid.

One of those fields is a date, and is parsed like "Mon Oct 17 00:00:00 UTC-0300 2016". Since Telerik controls return dates as string, I hace to expect a string parameter, convert it to a date format, and the excecute the stored procedure.

I can't convert the field in client side since the DataSource of the child grid is where I declare the parameters that the controller action will recieve. This is why I need to, once I reached the action, convert the string into the format I need before calling the stored procedure.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Something like `DateTime.Parse({your string}).ToString("mm/dd/yy")`

Comment: That exact sentence throws an error: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime". I've also tried with Convert.ToDateTime(my string) with no luck.

Comment: If really, telerik controls return dates as string, then I would suggest not using telerik. You can convert a date string to a datetime in the controller action using DateTime.TryParse() - also there are other ways to convert but this one is safer IMHO.

Comment: Is the time zone offset format *always* UTC-HHmm or UTC+HHmm? If so, that'll make things a bit simpler.

Comment: (I'd agree with @CetinBasoz that you should try to avoid using strings unless you really have to. I'd be very surprised if there were really no way of avoiding that.)

Comment: Not using Telerik grid is not an option. The company I work for uses it, and I have to work my way around it. @JonSkeet, supposing that the time zone format will always come in that way, how do you suggest I should proceed?

Comment: What I am saying is that, telerik shouldn't be doing that. I believe underlying source have property as datetime and that is just a display format - which is obviously a non-standard one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured out the format for your example string:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("Mon Oct 17 00:00:00 UTC-0300 2016", @"ddd MMM dd hh:mm:ss ""UTC""zzz yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        .ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
```

Comment: I'd suggest quoting the `UTC` part... it's also not obvious whether this will return the date in UTC or in the original time zone.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not exactly. A better way would be like:

DateTime dt;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact("Mon Oct 17 00:00:00 UTC-0300 2016",
 "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss UTCzzz yyyy",
 new CultureInfo("en-US"),
 DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
 Console.WriteLine(dt);
}

Comment: @JonSkeet What do you mean "quote the `UTC` part"? Also what is the obvious way to show what time zone it's in? I suppose I could stick `.ToUniversalTime()` or `.ToLocalTime()` on there.

Comment: @Quantic: I mean change "UTC" in your string to "'UTC'" to make it clear that the characters U, T and C are meant to be treated literally, rather than as format specifiers. As for the time zone part - I'd specify an appropriate `DateTimeStyles`. At the moment I really don't know what it would do...